# How do i make custom reordering for products in collection in shopify

Tags: shopify

How do i make custom reorder for products in collection in shopify. i mean for exapmle i have 'test' collection and i want to reorder products in 'test' collection by using product tag i mean i put some tags like 'firstshowup' in some product in 'test' collection so when customer click 'test' collection customer see products which have 'firstshowup' tag first and then  see the rest so what iam trying here is reordering using custom reordering not using like order by bestseller or allpabetically or date created s.t
thank you so much guys in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your collection will be made up of [Collect objects](http://api.shopify.com/collect.html), which have a position attribute. Assuming you're using a CustomCollection, you can modify the position of the Collects by updating the CustomCollection: http://api.shopify.com/customcollection.html#update

From the examples, to update a collection, you can use:

```
PUT /admin/custom_collections/#{id}.json
```

With the following payload:

```
{
  "custom_collection": {
    "body_html": "<p>The best selling ipod ever</p>",
    "handle": "ipods",
    "id": 841564295,
    "published_at": "2008-02-01T19:00:00-05:00",
    "sort_order": "manual",
    "template_suffix": null,
    "title": "IPods",
    "updated_at": "2008-02-01T19:00:00-05:00",
    "image": {
      "created_at": "2012-12-11T12:01:29-05:00",
      "src": "http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0006/9093/3842/collections/ipod_nano_8gb.jpg?0"
    },
    "collects": [
      {
        "product_id": 921728736,
        "position": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 841564295,
        "position": 2
      }
    ]
  }
}
```